# pig latin ruby translator issue

Tags: ruby

Hello I'm having trouble with my pig latin code, I'm working on the Learn First files from Ruby, what I basically wanted to do was the following, if a word began with a vowel=> apple would become appleay, if it began with a consonant => banana => ananabay, if it began with two consonants => cherry => errychay, it can also translate two words => eat pie would become eatay iepay and so on and so forth, here is my code:

```
def translate(string)

    vowels = [ "a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u"]
    alphabet = ("a" .. "z").to_a
    consonants = alphabet - vowels

    string_split = string.split

    string_split.map! do |w|
        if vowels.include?(w[0])
            w + 'ay'
        elsif consonants.include?(w[0]) &&

            consonants.include?(w[1])

            w [2..-1] + w [0..1]+ 'ay'

        elsif w [0..1] == "qu"

            w[2..-1] + "quay"

        elsif w[0..2] == "thr"

            w [3..-1]+"thray"

        elsif w[0..2]== "sch"

            w[3..-1]+"schay"

        elsif consonants.include?(w[0])

            w[ 1..-1] + w[0..0] + 'ay'
        else
                w

        end
    end

    return string_split.join(" ")

end
```

Comment: @mike when i try to run it with ruby prompt it says "translates a word beginning with vowel (FAILED -1)

Comment: First, start `irb` and `load` the file which contains this code. Then, try testing it and see whether it returns the desired output. For example, you can enter `translate("apple")` in `irb` and see what it returns.

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace and error message.

Comment: I stuck it in pry and got `translate("allo"); NoMethodError: undefined method 'elseif' for main:Object` OP, it is best to see the error messages, then you can see instantly that it doesn't know elseif, and then you can instantly see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple, it's `elsif` not `elseif`

```
def translate(string)

  vowels = [ "a" , "e" , "i" , "o" , "u"]
  alphabet = ("a" .. "z").to_a
  consonants = alphabet - vowels

  string_split = string.split

  string_split.map! do |w|
    if vowels.include?(w[0])
      w + 'ay'
    elsif consonants.include?(w[0]) &&

        consonants.include?(w[1])

      w [2..-1] + w [0..1]+ 'ay'

    elsif w [0..1] == "qu"

      w[2..-1] + "quay"

    elsif w[0..2] == "thr"

      w [3..-1]+"thray"

    elsif w[0..2]== "sch"

      w[3..-1]+"schay"

    else consonants.include?(w[0])

      w[ 1..-1] + w[0..0] + 'ay'


    end
  end

  return string_split.join(" ")

end
```

Comment: thanks I fixed it all now with the elsifs, and ran the program, it works up to the point where I need to translate three consonants, it says expected: "eethray" got: "reethay", but I have the line:   elsif w[0..2] == "thr"

      w [3..-1]+"thray" in my code, not sure why it's not working

Comment: @user3541885 Yes but you have the 2 consonent condition above the three consonant condition so that will never get executed. ruby tries every condition in order.

Comment: oh i see, is there a way that i can rewrite the code so that any of the conditions can be taken? sorry i am new to ruby and coding in general

Comment: just put the two consonant line at the bottom and think about what will be hit first in each case.

Comment: to learn about a more efficient way to solve this problem read about [regular expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm) and look at [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) oh and if this answer helped, just accept and upvote it.

Comment: thanks, i accepted it, i will upvote it when i have obtained 15 reptutation because i seem to need that first